# How to establish web socket on server side for chat implementation?

Tags: websocket, socket.io

If i don't have server details then who will establish or install the  web socket connection? Can admin (who handle our host) establish connection and provide me the URL of websocket to use in android or angular code?

Is this necessary to write code in php?

I expect server admin install and configure web socket and provide to use in chat module.

Answer (score 0):

Web admin(Ops) can help create the domain name but you have to write serverside code to handle websocket connection. You can use any programming language that supports websocket. for example,

- nodejs - https://github.com/websockets/ws
- java - https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/package-summary.html

**With java websocket you simply can define `ServerEndpoint` and deploy the `war`(web archive) to any host or cloud provider(Amazon cloud, google cloud etc),**

```
@ServerEndpoint("/chat/{clientId}")
public class MyWebsocketServer {

    @OnMessage
    public String handleMessage(@PathParam("clientId") String clientId,
                                                       String message, 
                                                       Session session) {
        System.out.println("chat message: " + clientId + "/" +message);
        return "hi how are you doing?";
    }
}
```

**Now, with javascript as a client** your code to establish WebSocket connection would be:

```
var clientId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2) + (new Date()).getTime().toString(36);
var webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/my-app/chat/" + clientId);
```

*localhost means I'm running both Server and Client in same host, in your case serving host might be www.mike-simons.com/chat while client running on phone*

Example: https://github.com/duwamish-os/chat-server_websocket-java

Comment: Thanks. How to use on Lumen or laravel? We are creating APIs on Lumen and use APIs on Android for mobile and Angular for web.